# How we can join the two tables if there is no common column values in spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables say `citizenship` and `country`:

```
country table
_______________
countryCode countryDescription

IN           INDIA
US           USA
UK           United kingdom
```

---

```
citizenship table
_________________
citizenshipId  CountryCode

1              +IN,+US
2               -IN,-UK
3               " "
4               null
```

I have to join the above tables in such a way that:

1. If there is (`+`) sign before `countryCode` in `citizenship` table then it should join with country tables  with `countryCode` and give me that number of records.
2. If there is (`-`) sign before the `countryCode` in `citizenship` table then it should join with country table and return the records except the countries with (`-`) sign.
3. If there is empty string or null then it should join with all the `countryCode` in `country` table.

Comment: Specify the expected result too.

Comment: And what should happen if the value is: `-IN,+UK`?

Answer (score 1):

If a `+` or a `-` at the beginning of `CountryCode` means that there is no case of `-` or `+` respectively, next, then you can do conditional joining like this:

```
select t.citizenshipId, t.CountryCode, 
  count(*) counter
from citizenship t inner join country c
on 1 = case left(t.CountryCode, 1)
  when '+' then concat(',', replace(t.CountryCode, '+', ''), ',') like concat('%,', c.countryCode, ',%')
  when '-' then concat(',', replace(t.CountryCode, '-', ''), ',') not like concat('%,', c.countryCode, ',%')
  else 1
end
group by t.citizenshipId, t.CountryCode
order by t.citizenshipId
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kZEtRBJKHgTTsrmSbYu8Hr/7).
Results:

```
| citizenshipId | CountryCode | counter |
| ------------- | ----------- | ------- |
| 1             | +IN,+US     | 2       |
| 2             | -IN,-UK     | 1       |
| 3             |             | 3       |
| 4             | null        | 3       |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do what is suggested here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
It is a SQL Server answer, but there may be similarities.

First you will want to clean up the citizenship table:

```
SELECT
citizenshipID, 
value AS CountryCode2
FROM 
citizenship
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(CountryCode,',')
```

This should return:

1   +IN
1   +US
2   " " 
etc.

Now we want the Join and cases

SELECT CountryCode2,
CASE WHEN CountryCode2 IS NULL THEN 'Nothing'
WHEN CountryCode2='' THEN 'Nothing'
ELSE LEFT(CountryCode2, 1) AS Sign,

CASE WHEN CountryCode2 IS NULL THEN 'Nothing'
WHEN CountryCode2='' THEN 'Nothing'
ELSE RIGHT(CountryCode2,2) AS Code, 
FROM
(
SELECT
    citizenshipID, 
    value AS CountryCode2
    FROM 
    citizenship
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(CountryCode,','))

This gives us the cleaned query that we can then join to the Country table

```
SELECT
Code, 
Description,
Sign,
SUM(Counter)
    FROM(
        SELECT A.Code AS Code, 
        B.CountryDescription AS Description,
        A.Sign AS Sign,
        '1' AS Counter
        FROM
            (SELECT CountryCode2,
            CASE WHEN CountryCode2 IS NULL THEN 'Nothing'
            WHEN CountryCode2='' THEN 'Nothing'
            ELSE LEFT(CountryCode2, 1) AS Sign,

            CASE WHEN CountryCode2 IS NULL THEN 'Nothing'
            WHEN CountryCode2='' THEN 'Nothing'
            ELSE RIGHT(CountryCode2,2) AS Code
            FROM
                (
                SELECT
                    citizenshipID, 
                    value AS CountryCode2
                FROM 
                    citizenship
                    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(CountryCode,','))) AS A
                JOIN country AS B ON A.Code=B.CountryCode)
GROUP BY Code, Description, Sign
```

I haven't tested it, but this might get you where you need to be. Note that I don't quite understand what you wanted with null and empty string values, so plug your logic there.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional join with `when` / `otherwise`.

If the `countryCode` column in citizenship table starts with `+` then join on `citizenship.countryCode contains country.countryCode`. If it starts with `-` then join on `citizenship.countryCode not contains country.countryCode`. If null or empty join with all lines in country.

Here is an example using Spark/Scala:

```
val countryDF = Seq(
("IN", "INDIA"), ("US", "USA"), ("UK", "United kingdom")
).toDF("countryCode", "countryDescription")

val citizenshipDF = Seq(
(1, "+IN,+US"), (2, "-IN,-UK"), (3, " "), (4, null)
).toDF("citizenshipId", "CountryCode")



val joinCondition = when(col("ct.countryCode").startsWith("+"), 
col("ct.countryCode").contains(col("c.countryCode"))).otherwise(
when(col("ct.countryCode").startsWith("-"), 
not(col("ct.countryCode").contains(concat(col("c.countryCode"))))
).otherwise(lit(true)))

countryDF.as("c").join(citizenshipDF.as("ct"), joinCondition).show()
```

Output:

```
+-----------+------------------+-------------+-----------+
|countryCode|countryDescription|citizenshipId|CountryCode|
+-----------+------------------+-------------+-----------+
|         IN|             INDIA|            1|    +IN,+US|
|         IN|             INDIA|            3|           |
|         IN|             INDIA|            4|       null|
|         US|               USA|            1|    +IN,+US|
|         US|               USA|            2|    -IN,-UK|
|         US|               USA|            3|           |
|         US|               USA|            4|       null|
|         UK|    United kingdom|            3|           |
|         UK|    United kingdom|            4|       null|
+-----------+------------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

So join only the positive, or join all minus the minus?

How about an inner join with some likes and unlikes.

```
SELECT *
FROM citizenship AS cish
JOIN country AS ctry
ON cish.CountryCode IS NULL
OR cish.CountryCode = ''
OR (cish.CountryCode LIKE '%+%' AND cish.CountryCode LIKE CONCAT('%+', ctry.CountryCode, '%'))
OR (cish.CountryCode NOT LIKE '%+%' AND  cish.CountryCode LIKE '%-%' AND  cish.CountryCode NOT LIKE CONCAT('%-', ctry.CountryCode,'%'))
ORDER BY cish.citizenshipId, ctry.CountryCode
```